# Random Josephus problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes

Josephus and 40 soldiers are playing a Game of Death.

At the beginning, **no.1** has a gun, he can kill the person on his left one (**no.41**  50%) or the person on his right (**no.2**  50%).

Then he gives the gun to the next person on his right who is still alive.

All subsequent agents face the same choice, until only the last one stands.

> Which side should Josephus start to have a higher survival probability?

Comment: "next one" that means if he kills no. 41, then no. 40 would get the gun. Am I right?

Comment: Does he pass the gun in ascending order of the positions or in the direction in which he killed (Does the gun move left if the left is killed and right if the right is killed, or always right or always left)

Comment: Right one, no. 2 if he killed no.41 or no. 3 if he killed no.2.

Comment: When a player is indifferent between Left and Right, how does it break a tie matters to the other players. *You should specify a tie-breaking rule.* If one assumes that in case of indifference the player passes the gun left or right with equal probability, there are multiple cases to consider. If one assumes that in case of indifferente the gun is always passed to the right, the problem looks simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The question of determining the probabilities of each of them to survive can be solved for arbitrary $n$ via recursion. We know, that if Josephus was alone, he would have been the survivor with probability $1$. If there are $n$ soldiers and one of them with a gun, then after he makes a shot we will have two similar tasks (for two outcomes) with $n - 1$ soldiers (but those soldiers in each of the cases will be different). This recursive method was implemented in the following Python code that solves the problem for $n$ soldiers ($n$ can be chosen manually):

```
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction

def rnext(l, a):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[(a + i)%len(l)] == 1:
            return (a + i)%len(l)
    return a

def lnext(l, a):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[(a - i)%len(l)] == 1:
            return (a - i)%len(l)
    return a

def singleton(n, a):
    l = np.asarray(list([0 for i in range(n)]))
    l[a] += 1
    return l

def josephus(l, a):
    if rnext(l, a) == a:
        return np.asarray(list([Fraction(i, 1) for i in list(singleton(len(l), a))]))
    else:
        return Fraction(1, 2)*(josephus(l - singleton(len(l), lnext(l, a)), rnext(l - singleton(len(l), lnext(l, a)), a)) + josephus(l - singleton(len(l), rnext(l, a)), rnext(l - singleton(len(l), rnext(l, a)), a)))

n = int(input())
l = np.ones(n)
j = josephus(l, 0)
for i in range(n):
    print(i, j[i])
```